# Pronunciation of 家

Tags: pronunciation, learning

In this sentence:

> ゆうむら家の３人は、半年前に**この家を**購入し、転居してきた。

この家を is pronounced as "kono yo" as opposed to "kono ie o".

And this phrase

> あんたは一人で**この家**から学校に通っている。

この家 is pronounced as "kono ye" as opposed to "kono ie".

So my question is, is this normal pronunciation for 家 when Japanese people talk normally/colloquially?

Note: sentence from Noir the anime, Episode 1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I do not know the anime, but 家を is never read as “yo,” and Japanese does not have “ye” sound at all.  What you heard as “yo” is probably “ie o” and what you heard as “ye” is probably “ie,” both just spoken fast.

Comment: Well, I know it's not read as "yo" but the anime pronounced it as "yo". That's why I was wondering if those pronounciations were normal in everyday japanese speaking.

Comment: Just to add. From a linguistic point of view, the high vowels [i] and [u] are respectively close to the glides [y] and [w]. So it is likely that they are misheard. And, dotnetNoob, are you particularly trained in phonology? (You don't seem to be a Japanese native either.) If not, please don't be too confident about your hearing.

Comment: So are you saying that "to iu" is always pronounced as "to i u" as opposed to "to yu (just like the english "you")"?

Comment: @sawa: though I appreciate the first half of your (first) answer, the second half (of your first answer) seemed unnecessary and condescending. Given the forum that I'm in, the specific question that I asked, and my tags are: pronounciation and learning", your question and following statement comes off as an attack than as an answer.

Comment: @sawa: I know my hearing isn't perfect. That's why I asked :)

Comment: @sawa, while phonology training would probably help, a native speaker will always hear allophones the "right" way, however they are pronounced. Someone could say /konjea:/ and people would still swear they heard このいえは.

Answer (score 2):

家 is read and pronounced as いえ　- i-e (yi-eh) or　うち　- u-chi.

In comparison, うち　sounds to me more informal, psychological, and subjective than いえ, which sounds formal, pysical and objective, like home versus house just for an analogy.

I would say:

彼のいえは大きい than　彼のうちは大きい、

(僕の)うちに遊びに来ない？ than (僕の)いえに遊びに来ない？

いえの守り神 than うちの守り神

and,

うちの家内は、うちの人は、not いえの家内は、いえの人は、

But it depends on your taste.

Comment: Are there many cases like this where one character can be read in different manners? If yes, is it always to sound more, or less, formal?